# Fetch the idToken using using amazon-cognito-identity-js javascript

Tags: node.js, requirejs, amazon-cognito, npm-install, aws-sdk-js

I want to Access to Codefi Compliance API endpoints that requires a valid idToken, which can be acquired using amazon-cognito-identity-js.

I have tried with this code and I am getting the error index.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Max</title>
<html>
<head>
<title>Max</title>

</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/node-fetch@2.6.0/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/amazon-cognito-identity-js@4.3.4/lib/index.min.js"></script>
<script>

global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
global.navigator = () => null;
global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

var authenticationData = {
Username : 'YOUR_USERNAME',
Password : 'YOUR_PASSWRD',
};
var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_22Qg1ksxH',
ClientId : '19dph7p79mhboibih2b9qk4j9p'
};
var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var userData = {
Username : 'YOUR_USERNAME',
Pool : userPool
};
var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
onSuccess: function (result) {
    
    /* Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with identity pools or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer*/
    var idToken = result.idToken.jwtToken;
    console.log('idToken:', idToken);
},

onFailure: function(err) {
console.error('ERRR: ', err);
},

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
</head>
<body>

<script>

global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
global.navigator = () => null;
global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

var authenticationData = {
    Username : 'YOUR_USERNAME',
    Password : 'YOUR_PASSWRD',
};
var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_22Qg1ksxH',
ClientId : '19dph7p79mhboibih2b9qk4j9p'
};
var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var userData = {
    Username : 'YOUR_USERNAME',
    Pool : userPool
};
var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        
        /* Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with identity pools or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer*/
        var idToken = result.idToken.jwtToken;
        console.log('idToken:', idToken);
    },

onFailure: function(err) {
    console.error('ERRR: ', err);
},

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think node-fetch is supported in the web browser. Just use the built in browser fetch

Comment: I updated the code by adding js libraries, still it gives me error

Comment: You are using RequireJS but your code uses CommonJS sytnax which is not compatible, that is why you are having errors

Comment: How to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The [amazon-cognito-identity-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js) NPM page says that you must either

- use bundler like Webpack or
- use NPM to download the package and source the `min.js` file from the downloaded `dist` directory.

The first option is the better long-term option as you'll end up with a build that downloads from fewer sources, but the second might be easier if you're just experimenting.

Following up on the second option, instead of using `require` you can run

`npm i amazon-cognito-identity-js`

and put the following ahead of where you source your own javascript in your HTML

`<script src="node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/dist/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js"></script>`

Make sure to adjust the `src="node_modules/...` path or move the `min.js` file to match your directory structure.